# PHP PDO won't prepare statement with NOW()

Tags: php, sqlite

I have some code that inserts a record into a SQLite table:

```
$statement = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO posts (postedOn, content, tags) VALUES (DATE('now'), :content, :tags)");
$statement -> bindParam(':content', $content);
$statement -> bindParam(':tags', $tags);
```

The problem is that the postedOn column only gets the date, and not the time of the post.  I tried using NOW() instead:

```
$statement = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO posts (postedOn, content, tags) VALUES (NOW(), :content, :tags)");
```

but I get

```
Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object
```

on the first bindParam call.  This works fine if I run it in SQLite 2009 Pro:

```
INSERT INTO posts (postedOn, content, tags) VALUES (NOW(), 'some content', 'tags')
```

Why doesn't prepare like NOW()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

There is no `NOW()` function in sqlite, try using `'now'` string in `datetime()`. SQLite 2009 Pro must have it's own implementation of this function, that you can try to implement in php on your own: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php

Answer (score 1):

Problem is NOW() function doesn't exist in SQLite. Instead use **datetime(‘NOW’,'localtime’)**. This is an example of alternative to [NOW function in SQLite](http://snippetsofcode.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/now-function-in-sqlite/)